# How different are iText and the iTextSharp port?

Tags: java, c#, itext

I'm interested in using iTextSharp in a C# project but documentation and examples seem to be lacking in the more detailed areas I'm interested in.  I'm very experienced in OOP concepts and have used Java some in the past (though it's been a while).  Since iTextSharp is a port of iText for Java, do you think that this book would be a good reference?  Are the Java and .NET versions too different for this to be of any benefit?  Or are there any other suggestions for examples?

[https://www.amazon.com/iText-Action-Covers-5/dp/1935182617/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1484850341&sr=1-1&keywords=itextsharp#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182617)

Thanks!

Comment: Book/library/site recommendations are off-topic on SO. Reviewing a book for applicability for particular topic is way too "opinion based"...

Comment: Speaking from experience, I did the original Java to C# code conversion for most of the [book examples here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed). Differences between Java and C# are **very** minor. E.g., Java has `getXX` and `setXX` methods, while .NET has properties. Some Java classes (imaging) do not exist in .NET. The book is over 6 years old, so one of the bigger problems you'll likely run into are API changes. With that said, I own the book, and it is still of value. See the [documentation pages](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) on the iText web site for usage examples.

Comment: Hmm, you're probably right. It points to a github page. If it is illegit git ought to remove it. I simply found it on google.. I had assumed it is open source and manning prints it for those who prefer a printed copy..

Comment: Of course I meant the book link. I have deleted the github link to it although I had it  at the back of my mind it might be os as well. The comment suspecting it being an illegit copy has also been deleted by now.

Comment: I nominated this question to reopen it. This question is not opinion based: this is a technical question that can be answered by explaining the possible difference in method names (uppercase vs lowercase; property vs getter/setter) and the difference between Drawing and Graphics2D. Those are technical differences; not opinion-based differences. It's a good question. I upvoted it.

Comment: As for the book I wrote: it's kind of outdated. The official web site has more interesting information. You can also get free vouchers for eBooks on LeanPub.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - the comment by `TaW` was in response to a comment from me that is completely unrelated to iText the company. We deleted both of those comments, and `TaW` is in no way questioning the legitimacy of iText software the company.

Comment: This question is a perfect example of one of the things that's horribly broken in SO. 4 upvotes, at least two of which are by people who are very knowledgeable about iText, and the question gets put on hold by people who have **zero to almost no activity** on  `itext` tagged questions. When I started learning iText as a .NET developer with **zero** experience with Java, I had **exactly** the same questions. The question title and first two sentences of the question are in **no way** asking for an _opinion based_ answer.

Comment: @kuujinbo Make your comment of Jan 19 into an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - comment posted as an answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from experience, I did the original Java to C# code conversion for most of the [book examples here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/). Differences between Java and C# are very minor. E.g., Java has `getXX` and `setXX` methods, while .NET has properties. Some Java classes (imaging) do not exist in .NET. The book is over 6 years old, so one of the bigger problems you'll likely run into are API changes.

With that said, I own the book, and it is still of value. See the [documentation pages](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) on the iText web site for usage examples.